# Is it possible to get the User Id without the authorization?

Tags: validation, facebook-php-sdk

Is it possible to get the user ID without authorization?

It used to work with `getUser` but it doesn't now. Are these new changes from Facebook or is there any other possibility to get user ID or the name to welcome the user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, users must give permission before you can get their user id.

Comment: in line which permission in scope would be the one to use as a minimum to get a user id?

Comment: you can get the user id withouth having extended permissions. If the user has logged in your app, you can get the basic data of the user (id, name and whatever you see in http://graph.facebook.com/USERNAME_OR_ID)

Comment: But can I get these data from a new User without accept any permissions? For the graph i need the Username or the Id, but how can I get them without permissions?

Comment: It's odd, I wonder how does the Javascript SDK do this (showing the profile picture in the Login Button before any permissions are granted).  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button

Answer (score 1):

See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

> Basic Information
>
> When a user allows you to access their basic information in an auth
>   dialog, you have access to their user id, name, profile picture,
>   gender, age range, locale, networks, user ID, list of friends, and any
>   other information they have made public.
>
> To get access to any additional information about the user or their
>   friends you need to ask for specific permissions from the user.