# Get Facebook User Id without Permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Possible duplicate , answered 2 years back [Is it possible to get the User Id without the authorization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730522/is-it-possible-to-get-the-user-id-without-the-authorization)

Just wanted to see if there is any mean I can fetch user id without showing permission dialog(not even the public permission dialog)

I have tried playing around with app token but in vain, Searched across documentation found no confirmed answers on this

Comment: Yeah just double checking no other way to know ? (-1) is one way to let me know

Answer (score 4):

**Deprecated answer**

Here is [the actual doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#usertokens) stating that reading a user's basic information needs the user to log in.

> **User Access Token** – The user token is the most commonly used type of
>   token. This kind of access token is needed any time the app calls an
>   API to read, modify or write a specific person's Facebook data on
>   their behalf. User access tokens are generally obtained via a login
>   dialog and require a person to permit your app to obtain one.

Basic information of a user **are** publicly available, without any token/login, but only if you already know the username/id of your target. Example:

```
graph.facebook.com/zuck

{
   "id": "4",
   "name": "Mark Zuckerberg",
   "first_name": "Mark",
   "last_name": "Zuckerberg",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/zuck",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "en_US",
   "username": "zuck"
}
```

But getting the basic information of whoever is on your page is impossible without login. How is it possible to guess who is behind? Reading cookies of another site is 1) impossible 2) forbidden.

Comment: Not sure, why user id is stated as publicly available

Comment: Hi @Stéphane Bruckert.
Facebook is no more providing user information without Access Token
https://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX

{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104,
      "fbtrace_id": "BUeBLddZiB8"
   }
}